# Is there a way to get the list of a the Pages that a Facebook Page likes?

Tags: facebook

Pages on Facebook can like other Pages. Is there a way to get the list of Pages that a Page (not a User) likes via the Open Graph API? I don't see that documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's  similar to users:

```
/[page_id or name]/likes
```

edit:
You don't need any permissions, You can ask about any pages' likes

Comment: Thanks, looks like an access token is required, but I can live with that.